# How do you check if value exist in object of object's array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to know which logic i should use to check every object's array of parent object contained in grand parent object

Hi guys i want to check if this value for example : "127.0.0.1" exists in this object (MyObject has like 2k objects in it)

```
{
  "name" : MyObject
  "value": [
      {
        "name" : "Object1",
        "properties":{
          "address" : [
             "13.65.25.19/32",
             "13.66.60.119/32",
           ]
         }
      },
      {
        "name" : "Object2",
        "properties":{
          "address" : [
             "13.65.25.19/32",
             "127.0.0.1",
           ]
         }
      }
    ]
}
```

Btw does include() needs to match the whole string or for example if 127.0.0.1 is like this in my object 127.0.0.1/32, i can still retrieve it even if there is a ip range ?

Comment: [Array.includes docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

[String.includes docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: @tbjgolden yeah i know these "basics" things, but with multiple array and object at the same time, i'm kinda lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is structured quite specifically, so you can write a custom method which you can call over and over again. It will check for a

```js
const obj = {
    name: 'MyObject',
    value: [
        {
            name: 'Object1',
            properties: {
                address: ['13.65.25.19/32', '13.66.60.119/32'],
            },
        },
        {
            name: 'Object2',
            properties: {
                address: ['13.65.25.19/32', '127.0.0.1'],
            },
        },
    ],
};

const address = '127.0.0.1';

const includesAddress = (address) => {
    for (const val of obj.value) {
        if (val.properties.address.some((a) => address === a)) return true;
    }
    return false;
};

console.log(includesAddress(address));
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but can i for example like i wrote on the last line of my first post, if adress array contains "127.0.0.1/32"  return also true ? Would it be a regex thing or i'm completely wrong ? Because here my const address = 13.65.25.19, it will return false even if "include" is supposed to return true since it exist object1 & object2

Comment: At that point you can use regex yes

Comment: but include() isnt supposed to that ?

Comment: This code will work just fine if you have "127.0.0.1/32", because it includes "127.0.0.1"

Comment: @traha No this will fail in this case. Please see my solution for correct implementation.

Comment: @Nitheesh I'd love to know why you think `'127.0.0.1/32'.includes('127.0.0.1')` will fail. Perhaps try it in your own environment?

Comment: Check the difference between array.includes and string.includes. tried your solution in my environment in the above scenario and I can see the solution clearly fails.

Comment: @Nitheesh good catch. too right

Comment: added solution to new edit

Comment: @mstephen19 nice. Now this logic looks same as my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.flatMap` implementation

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'MyObject',
  value: [
    {
      name: 'Object1',
      properties: {
        address: ['13.65.25.19/32', '13.66.60.119/32'],
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'Object2',
      properties: {
        address: ['13.65.25.19/32', '127.0.0.1'],
      },
    },
  ],
};

const address = '127.0.0.1';
const output = obj.value.flatMap(item => item.properties.address).includes(address);
console.log(output);
```

If you want  check if the partial ip addess is included in the list, you should make use of a regex implementation.

**Sample Implementation**

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'MyObject',
  value: [
    {
      name: 'Object1',
      properties: {
        address: ['13.65.25.19/32', '13.66.60.119/32'],
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'Object2',
      properties: {
        address: ['13.65.25.19/32', '127.0.0.1'],
      },
    },
  ],
};

const address = '13.65.25.19';
const regex = new RegExp(address, 'i')
const output = obj.value.flatMap(item => item.properties.address).filter(x => regex.test(x)).length > 0;
console.log(output);
```